# Get number of changed files in Git between two branches from bash

Tags: git

I'd like to know how can I get a number of changed files between two branches in a bash script i.e.

```
git diff v1.1.123..master --stat
```

and this gives a list of files and detailed changed/added/deletion, but I'd need the number of changed files in a bash variable.

OR, anyway to find out if there has been any change between the branches in a bash variable, so that I can do some operations if there's any change or not.

Comment: You are already most of the way there.  Simply replace `--stat` with `--name-status` and then write the code to count based on the statuses.  (Note also that `git diff X..Y` means precisely the same thing as `git diff X Y`: the usual special meaning of `..`, two dots, goes away in `git diff`.)

Comment: @torek : sweet! `git diff v1.1.123 master --name-status | wc -l` did the job. Please submit as answer and I'll make it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Answer copied and expanded from comment, though this is now largely a duplicate of several "name or name-status only" questions as well.)

You are already most of the way there. Simply replace `--stat` with `--name-status` and then write code to count based on the statuses. (Note also that `git diff X..Y` means precisely the same thing as `git diff X Y`: the usual special meaning of `..`, two dots, goes away in `git diff`.)

`--name-only` would work as well if you don't care to aggregate stats for Add, Delete, Modify, and potentially Copy, Rename, Type-change (e.g., from regular file to symlink), etc.  Whether your diff will detect renames depends on (a) file similarity and (b) options and/or your setting for `diff.renameLimit`.  Copy detection is similarly under the control of options.  Note that you can also use `--diff-filter` to select for (or, since git 1.8.5, exclude<sup>1</sup>) particular changes.

To just count files, piping the diff output through `wc -l` will suffice (though note that its output has leading white space).

---

<sup>1</sup>For instance, `git diff A B --name-status --diff-filter=AD` will produce just a list of files Added or Deleted.  To exclude Type-change items, `git diff A B --name-status --diff-filter=t` does the trick in git 1.8.5 or newer; with older versions, you would have to list everything *but* `T`, e.g., `--diff-filter=ABCDMRUX`, depending on whether you asked for pairing breaks.  I'll also note that Unmerged and X(unknown) should never occur here; `U` status should only occur when invoking a diff against the index.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `--diff-filter` to count just added or deleted files too. That's exactly what I needed! (I think that's basically equivalent to piping through `grep '^[AD]'`?)

Answer (score 3):

if A and B are different branches, type

`git diff A..B --name-status`

Answer (score 1):

Execute this command and execute a count on the files

```
 git diff --name-only SHA-1 SHA-2
```

If you just want to count files:

> ***`git-whatchanged`***
>   - Show logs with difference each commit introduces

```
 # replace the -1 with the desired number of commits you need
 # the output will be a number for the modified files,
 git whatchanged -1 --format=oneline | wc -l
```

---

To get a full list of files (names and more, simply remove the `wc` )

```
git whatchanged -1 --format=oneline
```

Comment: The `git whatchanged` command is slowly being phased out, with `git log --raw` as its recommended replacement.  After a few years I can finally remember `--raw` now instead of going straight for `git whatchanged` :-)

Comment: if he has a newer version of git he can also use `git log --cc -n <number of commits>` and set the suitable format he wants as output

Comment: For example this will print out all the modified files (without formatting)  `git log --cc -n 10 --name-only --summary --graph --decorate`

Comment: The `--cc` option to `git log` affects how merges are shown; that does not seem like the kind of thing one would want here...